# Restore dump locally without pre-existing database

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I have received a backup file from a customer and wish to restore it.

I've tried executing the following on the command line (which runs for ages, seems to get to the end, but does not produce a new database in my `localhost` server).

```
pg_restore --create -h localhost c:\temp\myBackup.backup
```

I've also tried to run the restore through pgAdmin4 but it reports that indexes already exist if I tried to create an empty database and restore into it and I can't seem to locate the correct options to restore the database and create a new one (without having first selected an empty database).

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. I'm happy to use any method.

Comment: Arg, solved this, I needed to create an empty db by the same name, then restore into with the `create` option set. Seems kind of counter intuitive to me! Dear pgAdmin authors, can you please include a 'restore' option at the server level so I can point to a backup file and restore directly, rather than needing to create a blank db and then immediately overwrite it!

Comment: You can do that easily - just use `-d postgres --create`. The backup won't be restored into `postgres`, only `pg_restore` needs to connect to a database to issue the `CREATE DATABASE` command.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe thanks for the info, that sounds sensible.